# Change forward-word/backward-word/kill-word for CamelCase Words in Emacs

Tags: emacs, syntax, intellij-idea, camelcasing

I need to ability to navigate and edit parts of a camel cased word in Emacs. Functionality similar to camel humps in Intellij IDEA.
For example I need *Blah,Foo* and *Bar* in the string **BlahFooBar** to be identified as 3 separate words so I could navigate/edit them like they are separate words.

I have tried playing with syntax table

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?A ".")
(modify-syntax-entry ?F ".")
```

This has the effect of making *lah, oo*, and *ar* words and chars B and F word separators. So the navigation backwards (and backward-kill-word) does not work as expected.

What I need is word boundaries based on regex and not a separator.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd>`subword-mode` should do exactly that.

Comment: Hey Thanks. This is a better solution, since it comes packaged with emacs.

Comment: @Gizak (via [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6328229)): Post that as a separate answer.  Edits that add in an alternative method should generally be posted as new answers.

Answer (score 1):

Get py-forward-, resp. py-backward-into-nomenclature from python-mode.el

It works with any mode

https://launchpad.net/python-mode/+download

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be camelcase mode.
http://www.eecs.ucf.edu/~leavens/emacs/camelCase/camelCase-mode.html